# MongoDB database operations not working in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to work with MongoDB in Node.js but it is not working with the simplest code.

The **Simplest** Code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

error:

```
D:\Clg\Sem-5\Software Packages\Lab\Practical-7\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:292
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Clg\Sem-5\Software Packages\Lab\Practical-7\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:292:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 2642697,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\Clg\Sem-5\Software Packages\Lab\Practical-7\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:387:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Clg\Sem-5\Software Packages\Lab\Practical-7\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:310:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.7.0
```

I tested error in both latest version as well as v5.0.13 but I have same error & when I searched on internet I found there should be problem with MongoDB service but when I checked for same. I found that service is already running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to the file in the given path will be helpful

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin\mongod.cfg"
```

at least these 4 lines must be inside the "net" portion

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  ipv6: true
  bindIpAll: true
```

Answer (score 1):

`ECONNREFUSED` usually means MongoDB is not running at the URL you are supplying, or that your application cannot access that port. Are you definitely running MongoDB locally on port number 27017? You will need to make sure that your local MongoDB instance is up and available - try accessing it through the browser by navigating to `localhost:27017`.

Comment: yes, I am running it over 27017. I am sure it is available because I fired "mongod" & "mongo" in 2 different cmd terminals after that when I tried to enter "localhost:27017" in the browser then I got a message     ``` It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.```      after that, I tried to enter "mongodb://localhost:27017/" then it made a google search

Comment: If you successfully ran `mongod` in one of the two shell sessions _after_ you tried the application then that might suggest that it wasn't at the time you tried the app. If you can start up the `mongod` process then it means that there wasn't already one running on the provided port (`27017` by default)